# Как прятать адресную панель в safari ios?

Tags: css

Привет!
Что нужно прописать в css, что бы при скролле прятались панели в safari? Это адресная и навигационная снизу.
Гуглом попользовался, не помогло.
Беда вот в чем, на лендскейпе футер и хедер остаются под этими панелями.
Структура шаблона:

```css
.b-page-wrapper {
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.b-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  z-index: 1010;
}

.b-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="b-page-wrapper js-this-scroll">
    <header class="b-header b-header--page404"></header>
    <main class="b-wrapper">
      <div class="b-wrapper__main"></div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Вот примерно так хотелось бы сделать, но на css

[image]

Comment: Это при помощи CSS сделать нельзя!

Comment: при чём css и адресная строка в браузере ? наверняка есть  вкладка ВИД и в ней это можно сделать

Comment: @Shnur как тогда быть? Например на яндекс маркете это работает. Проскроливаю и панели скрываются, остается только небольшая адресная строка.

Comment: Уточните о какой конкретно, идет речь, адресной строке и навигации снизу? предоставьте более раскрытый вопрос, нельзя при помощи CSS изменять внешний вид браузера.

Comment: @Shnur обновил.

Comment: Да все верно это при помощи CSS не правиться.

Comment: @Shnur как с этим боролись? Есть предположение, что скрипт, который есть в сети уже не рабочий, последнее обновление 3 года назад было.

Comment: у меня нет при себе iPhone чтобы проверить это поведение на других сайтах, знаю только одно что на андройде при скролле адресная строка пропадает автоматом. это заложено в сам браузер.

Comment: у вас не пропадает, потому-что у вас скроллится контейнер а боди , браузер только на боди скролле убирает панели

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо! Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev странно, на body скроллится не хочет.

Comment: @drtvader высота контента больше окна?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev да, высота контента больше окна.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev только вот высоту body не удается сделать под высоту контента.